# c++ visual studio 2010 - How to create a project under a different folder name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I would like to have a the following structure of folders:

Myproj\src

Myproj\include

Myproj\lib

Myproj\src should include all sources and project files etc.

EDIT: also, $(projectDir) should equal Myproj\src

The problem is with Myproj\src, when I create a new project in VS2010 a folder named \Myproj is created and in it all sources are placed. How can I break this connection and have my desired structure made?

A TFS friendly solution would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create a project, you can change the folders where certain files are stored. When you right-click the project in solution browser, there will be option for VC++ Directories - Include Directories.

If you add your $(ProjectDir)\src and $(ProjectDir)\include to this field, you will be able to put your files in these places. However, default VS creators, such as "Add Class" will still add your files to Project folder.

As for "lib" - I am guessing you are trying to create a library project. For that, you must find the "General->Output directory", and change it accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to actually change ProjectDir. I also really don't know why you would want to do that.
The thing is, ProjectDir contains all of project build files (source etc.), so its natural to keep all files in it. You can always create folder structure inside it, but I'm not sure why you would want to keep includes and libs outside it.

Comment: Having many projects in my solution, it's so that when I enter a project's folder I can have a clear view of the hierarchy: libs, include, src (which contains bin and more folders that would otherwise pollute my clean view)

Comment: settled for an in between solution